# Carregar tabela do banco por sessão sistema

Tags: c#, sql, static

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, onde um dos módulos é o cadastro de produtos, e dentro desse cadastro, tenho a parte fiscal.

Nesta parte fiscal, tenho que definir um NCM, e conseguintemente a alíquota IPI, então elaborei uma tabela com código NCM, descrição e aliquota, porem minha tabela ficou com 10029 registros.

minha duvida é, ou ate melhor, qual seria a sugestões de vocês, sobre carregar essa tabela uma vez por seção do sistema? 
Teria uma `classe static`, parecida com essa:

```
public static class Cidades
{
    private static DataTable _tableCidade;

    public static DataTable Tablecidade
    {
        get { return Cidades._tableCidade; }
        set { Cidades._tableCidade = value; }
    }
}
```

que ao realizar o login no sistema, seria populado o `datatable`, com essa tabela de ncm e aliquotas ipi.

oque acham?

Em analise, de consumo de memoria, tive um aumento de 5 mb no consumo, em questao de velocidade, não senti diferença entre carregar ela no inicio ou nao carregar.

Obs: Ah quem interessar, posso disponibilizar, esta em linguagem SQL com a ultima versão atualizada retirada do site oficial da receita.

Comment: Aconselho você a não utilizar Sessions para essa finalidade, o que você quer é criar cache dos dados, e para isso existe o Redis http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636730/Distributed-Caching-using-Redis

Comment: hum.. vou ler sobre obrigado.